# What does resultSet.next() do

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a simple question. If my procedure is returning 500 rows then in line 1 my result set is having 500 rows. This means now all the records are present in this resultset object. Am I correct ?

If rs.next iteration is taking time this means it's not related to stored procedure performance because we already got the resultset object at Java side which contains all 500 records. Am I correct ?

```
rs = (ResultSet)callableStatement.getObject(1);
logger.debug("Iterating ResultSet Starts");
Bean bean = null;
while(rs.next()) {
    logger.debug(“some logic but commented to check performance”);     
}
```

Comment: you already asked similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742097/performance-issue-resultset-iteration) Its time for you to google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CallableStatement and ResultSet both have a fetch size that decides how many rows at a time are retrieved from the cursor when iterating through the result set. By default you do not get all 500 rows, you get a number of rows up to the driver's fetch size. According to [this Oracle JDBC documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/resltse5.htm) Oracle's default fetch size is a lot lower:

> By default, when Oracle JDBC executes a query, it receives the result set 10 rows at a time from the database cursor. This is the default Oracle row-prefetch value. You can change the number of rows retrieved with each trip to the database cursor by changing the row-prefetch value (see "Oracle Row Prefetching" for more information).
>
> JDBC 2.0 also allows you to specify the number of rows fetched with each database round trip for a query, and this number is referred to as the fetch size. In Oracle JDBC, the row-prefetch value is used as the default fetch size in a statement object. Setting the fetch size overrides the row-prefetch setting and affects subsequent queries executed through that statement object.
>
> Fetch size is also used in a result set. When the statement object executes a query, the fetch size of the statement object is passed to the result set object produced by the query. However, you can also set the fetch size in the result set object to override the statement fetch size that was passed to it. (Also note that changes made to a statement object's fetch size after a result set is produced will have no affect on that result set.)

With the default setting of 10 your code would make 50 round trips to get all the data from the procedure call. (This documentation is pretty old -- it talks about JDBC 2.0 as if it's new -- so it may be out of date, you should check out what your fetch size gets set to.) Changing the fetch size in order to get back all the rows at once should minimize the overhead from trips across the network.

Answer (score 1):

> This means now all the records are present in this resultset object. am i correct ?

Usually this is not correct. `ResultSet` is normally an abstraction on the database cursor, which will fetch records of the result set on demand, when `next` is called.

Only in some exceptional cases you'll get what is called a "client-side cursor", which means that all the data has been copied to your side in advance. This is an undesirable behavior and is a workaround for cases where the JDBC specification demands something that the database does not natively support.